# Mean statistics about agents in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm working on a family practitioner model, my goal is to model the population of a city and all of the family practitioners in that given city by taking into account the distribution of the treatment time and the arrival schedule of patients etc... So far i've managed to create an agent that contains a bloc diagram to model the whole process
[image]
With a source and a delay bloc to generate patients according to a fixed schedule, a service bloc and two sinks.

Now i've put a population of this agent "process" in the main and i've simulated the model for 3 months.
[image]
Lets say i've started with a population of 10 process which represents the number of practitioners. My goal now to to collect some Mean statistics, like the Mean number of treated patients (treated patients goes to the sink "Served") of the 10 practitioners, the Mean waiting time of patients at the service bloc, the mean utilization ratio of the resource of the service bloc...

I want to also know if is it possible to limit the total number of Patients (or to at least count them), for exemple, instead of simulating the model for 3 months, i wanna limit the total number of patients that goes to the 10 process to 10k and i want to know how much time does it take to serve all of them. (is it possible with this architecture of the model or do i have to make major changes)
Thank you

Comment: Hey, please always ask separate questions separately. Also, best do not ask "is it possible" (the answer is always "yes" in AnyLogic). Better show what you tried already and why that does not work. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . We are happy to help but you need to make our lives as easy as possible :D

Comment: btw: Architecture is good so far, good baseline. Check the statistics tab in your "process" agent population and do the step-by-step AnyLogic tutorials, they cover agent-population statistics in detail

Comment: Okay thank you! well the tutorials helped me get this far :) ill check again i'm sure i've missed alot of stuff

Comment: Whenever i try to create a charte in main i get the following probleme "cannot make a static reference to the non static field"
I've used the following codes : Process.service.queueSize.mean()/Process.service.statsUtilization.mean()

Comment: I've read that main is static field thats why i get this type of error but i honestly have no clue what that mean

Comment: As in my first comment: always ask separate questions in new issues here on SOF. This place is not a forum but a Q&A place. Also, use the search first always. This error has been asked about a ton of times before :)